# Rounded edges with RoundRect are not smooth

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

[image: rounded rectaangle]
I am drawing a rounded corner rectangle using RoundRect windows API.

```
RoundRect(hdc,0,0,100,100,4,4);
```

Here I am drawing rectangle with rounded corner width and height = 4 px.

After that I want to fill the rounded rectangle. For that I am creating rectangular region using

```
CreateRoundRectRgn
```

and then calling 
FillRgn  API.

Problem is that after filling I can see fill color outside rounded corners also. Since I am creating rounded region, filling should only be inside that region.

Any ideas why its going outside rounded rectangle?

Answer (score 4):

`RoundRect` already fills the rectangle using the current brush.  Just use `SelectObject` to select the brush you want.

Which makes the following observations somewhat redundant.  `RoundRect` and `CreateRoundRectRgn` interpret the coordinates differently.  `RoundRect`'s coordinates are inclusive but `CreateRoundRectRgn`'s are exclusive at the bottom-right (so you have to add one to the bottom-right coordinates in the latter case).

And since Windows doesn't provide a function to get a region corresponding to the interior of a rounded rectangle, you'll never get pixel-perfect accuracy if you fill it yourself (the interior of a rounded rectangle is not the same as a slightly smaller rounded rectangle).